# Wait, how did this low-rep user just review a suggested edit?

Tags: support, privileges

Ok, so I just glanced over the [review queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review) and noticed a new face:

[image: Review queue as at 2017-02-21 1:30pm AEDT]

Nothing unusual, except for the fact that that user has [47 rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/78734/beatsforthemind?tab=profile).

[image: Expanded part of review queue which shows user's profile and rep, which stands at 47].

**Huh?**

[The minimum rep required to be able to access the review queues is 500 rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

So, **how did this low-rep user review this "suggested edit"?**

Answer (score 12):

**The user performed the review action on one of their own posts**

The system is designed in such a way that it can track when your action happens to match up with one you would take if you were reviewing. In this case, there was a [suggested edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/100286) to one of their own posts, which they promptly approved, thus registering as a review action. See below image:

[image: Image showing that the user in question approved an edit suggestion which happened to also be in the review queue.]